# Moya Requests take a long time to respond

Tags: swift, moya

Moya requests take around extra 7 seconds before giving back a response, as opposed to any request with Alamofire or URLSession that take few milliseconds ...

```
var method: Moya.Method {
    switch self {
    case .foo:
        return .get
    case .bar:
        return .get
    }
}

var task : Task {
    switch self {
    case .foo:
        return .requestParameters(parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    case .bar:
        return .requestParameters(parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> disclaimer : this is answered directly using the option "Answer your
>   own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"

using `URLEncoding` along with get requests, makes the response show up directly, it looks like a bug in moya.

```
var task : Task {
    switch self {
    case .foo:
        return .requestParameters(parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
    case .bar:
        return .requestParameters(parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
    }
}
```